# I'm Looking for better Armour for my Kasatha Gunslinger

Tags: pathfinder-1e, armor

I've been playing a campaign with some friends and I have a nearly reached level 7 with my Kasatha Gunslinger(Pistolero) and Bard(Juggler) combo. I recently realised that I have a dex mod of +6 and so my Armour (Studded Leather) won't really help me as much seeing as it has a maximum Dex bonus of +5. I'm looking for new Armour to replace my studded leather and am not sure what to get. Price range of up to about 20K gp Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Being a Bard, you're most likely sticking to Light Armor because they are allowed to cast without fear of losing their spell in Light Armor. This provides you with a few options that better leverage your Dex to AC:

1. Darkleaf Cloth Studded Leather: 3 AC and Max Dex 7
   Price: 525g (+ Enhancement)
2. Mithral Chain Shirt (also known as [Mithral Shirt](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-armor/specific-magic-armor/mithral-shirt/)): 4 AC and Max Dex 6
   Price: 1100g (+ Enhancement)
3. Mithral Parade Armor: 3 AC and Max Dex 7
   Price: 1025g (+ Enhancement)
4. Darkleaf Cloth Hide Shirt: 3 AC and Max Dex 6
   Price: 520g (+ Enhancement)

A couple notes

- The Chain Shirt may be a better buy if you're not planning on increasing your Dex further, but the Darkleaf Cloth Studded Leather is an oft-overlooked cheaper item that allows a higher Dex value. Dex AC is more valuable than Armor AC because it also affects your Touch AC (although a balance is good if you can be caught flat-footed, Touch AC is used far more frequently).
- Parade Armor and Hide Shirt are simply inferior to the first 2 armors given your budget, but I included them for posterity.
- Parade Armor gives a +2 Circumstance bonus to Diplomacy and Intimidate to citizens of the country it's made for, if that matters to you.
- Your maximum Enhancement (magic) bonus, in-budget, is +4 for all these armors. Upping to +5 will be around 25,500-26,500.

---

Honorable Mentions:

These are outside of budget or don't leverage your AC, as requested, but these Chainmails-turned-Light-armor also increase your AC.

5. [Celestial Armor](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-armor/specific-magic-armor/celestial-armor/): 9 AC and Max Dex 8
   Price: 22,400 *includes base +3 Enhancement*
6. [Elven Chain](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-armor/specific-magic-armor/elven-chain/): 6 AC and Max Dex 4
   Price: 5150g (+ Enhancement)

Comment: Isn't the celestial armor a +3?

Comment: Yes, but it's static unless your GM allows you to upgrade it was my intended meaning. I'll clarify